# Regex: Date Exact Match

Tags: regex, date, formula

I have a little problem on a date-time

**april 15, 2014**

I wrote this regex: \D+[a-z] \d{2}, \d{1,4}

The problem is when I have text before date, for example:

**text text april 15, 2014 text**

Well, in this case my regex selects also the text, not only the date. So I need to modify a little bit my regex to find strictly my date, and not the text before or after.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `[a-zA-Z]+` to match the month names:

```
[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2}, \d{1,4}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKGC6f/1)

Also, consider using word boundaries, `\b[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2}, \d{1,4}\b`, if you need to match these strings inside a larger string, or consider using anchors if you need a *full string* match: `^[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2}, \d{1,4}$`.

Just a note: `\d{1,4}` matches 1 to 4 digits. If you plan to match 4-digit years, use `\d{4}`. If you plan to match 2- or 4-digit years, use `(\d{4}|\d{2})`, but this time you really need either word boundaries or anchors.

Comment: @Drako: That depends on where the text is to be matched. I added that in the additinal notes.

Answer (score 1):

For your case you should be careful, because may your **date** would be something like this:
**april**`a lot of space`**15**`space`,`space`**2014**
Then this regex is not safe:
`[a-zA-Z]+ \d{2}, \d{1,4}`  It matches as you want but **safety?** No because a **single** `space` break the rule for that.

And this is a safe regex for you:
`\w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+`

And you can still make it safer by surrounded `^` and `$` and the most safe regex for you is:
`^\w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+$`

[prove](https://regex101.com/r/BmDErI/1)